# Load JavaScript from a node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node server that should deliver on localhost:8888 index.html file.

index.html :

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Can I load both index.html and app.js from a node server ?

Comment: No! But, why would you want to run a server side code on the client?

Comment: Are you using Express.js? http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: app.js is not a server script, it is for the client. @ParthapratimNeog

Comment: No @IanJones Thanks for the tip

Comment: Ok, by loading from a Node server, what exactly do you mean? Use the file to process on the backend? or something like that? Can you please be clear.

Comment: you can serve both the index.html and app.js... its possible... are you using express.js? its just both the client should reside in the same server and you serve it...

Comment: Static resources. The below answer from Aaron Conran explains the concept

Answer (score 0):

There are several server-side frameworks that will easily serve up static resources assuming that index.html and app.js reside in the same directory.

Take a look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [hapi](http://hapijs.com/) and [koa](http://koajs.com/) for example. The search term that you are looking for is "static resources".

Additionally if you are interested in just raw node.js APIs take a look at the http.createServer api. Googling node.js basic http server or static resources you will find lots of hits.